How to implement iOS Live Activity Without Dynamic Island
i want to implement live activity to my project. But i want it without dynamic island. SwiftUI doesn't let me to remove dynamicIsland closure. Is that possible to implement only the live activity part on lock screen ?
I couldn't find any useful information about this.
